# Keras del stuck with constant loss and accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to train a keras CNN against the Street View House Numbers Dataset. You can find the project [here](https://github.com/asindico/digitRecognition/tree/9faa600f956e264ca61afe48d64c833f8b58711c). The problem is that during training neither loss nor accuracy change over time. I have tried with 1 Channel (Gray Scale) images, with RGB (3 channels) images, with wider (50,50) and smaller (28,28) images, with more or less filters in the convolutional layers, with wider and smaller patches in the pooling layers, with and without dropout, with bigger and smaller batches, with smaller and bigger learning step for the optimizers, with different optimizers, ...

Still the training gets stuck to constant loss and accuracy

Comment: How many epoches did you run?

Comment: @Sindico Your network is shallow. Add more convolution layers so that they can capture more higher level features. For example, you can try to build a network similar to VGG16 or you may even use the VGG16 with pre-trained weights and then fine tuning it.